# SIGALRM blocked by a mask

Tags: unix, signals

I have a doubt about what happens when a SIGALRM signal gets blocked, does it go into pending state and delivered after it is unblocked or does it get lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIGALRM is held pending, and will be delivered as soon as it is unblocked.

A blocked signal (SIG_BLOCK) remains pending until it is:

1. *delivered*, by being unblocked and having either a default (SIG_DFL or "uncaught") disposition or a user-supplied ("caught") disposition, as by `struct sigaction`'s `sa_handler`.
2. *accepted*, by [`sigwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigwait.html), [`sigwaitinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigwaitinfo.html), or [`sigtimedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigwaitinfo.html), meaning it is removed from the set of pending signals without further action
3. *discarded*, by changing its disposition to SIG_IGN ("ignored").  Already ignored signals [will not be held pending in any case](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_03)

Conventional UNIX signals typically do not queue, so only one signal of a given type may be pending at a time, and subsequently generated signals of the same type will be lost.

(As an aside, the implementation chooses the order of signal delivery and acceptance, for example, always delivering or accepting lower-numbered signals before higher-numbered signals.  This means that your newly unblocked SIGALRM might not be delivered first if other signals are ready for delivery.  In practice, however, it will be delivered immediately.)